# Crate cannot find path

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am trying to use this crate to generate an ethereum address: https://docs.rs/ethkey/0.2.5/ethkey/

```
use ethkey::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let key = EthAccount::load_or_generate("~/", "passwd")
        .expect("should load or generate new eth key");

    println!("{:?}", key.address())
}
```

This is the example from the documentation and it doesnt seem to work. 
I get the error below:

> cargo run    Compiling ethkey v0.1.0
>   (/Users/samueldare/Documents/Code/Thor/ethkey)
>       Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.34s
>        Running `target/debug/ethkey` thread 'main' panicked at 'should load or generate new eth key: Error(IoError(Os { code: 2, kind:
>   NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }), State { next_error:
>   None, backtrace: InternalBacktrace { backtrace: None } })',
>   src/libcore/result.rs:999:5 note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`
>   environment variable to display a backtrace.

Ive use `~/` as a last attempt to generate the key file in rust, but it still doesnt seem to work.

I will appreciate any pointers with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `load_or_generate()` takes a [std::path::Path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html) with no closing slash ( '/' ).  Remove the slash:

```
fn main() {
    let key = EthAccount::load_or_generate("~", "passwd")
        .expect("should load or generate new eth key");

    println!("{:?}", key.address())
}
```

Sample output:

```
05:47 ethtest (master) ✗ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running `target/debug/ethtest`
Address(0x8248af6d1765e559509060b88e540a3567c42d20)
05:47 ethtest (master) ✗
```

Comment: Thanks! that works for the home, but when i try to put it in a file like : `/Users/Documents/Code/Thor/thor/parity/keys` i get the following error: `thread 'main' panicked at 'should load or generate new eth key: Error(SerdeJsonError(Error("Is a directory (os error 21)", line: 0, column: 0)), State { next_error: None, backtrace: InternalBacktrace { backtrace: None } })', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace` thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like a new question :-).  Your first question is a great [mcve].  The comment, is really a brand new question.  Please present it with its own [mcve] in a new question, after accepting the answer in this question.

Comment: I have written a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201720/cannot-write-keyfile-with-crate thanks for your help!!